# Script calling ssh; want to create log on local machine

Tags: ssh, networking, logs

I need to create a script which logs into all the servers listed in `servers.txt`. I want to use password, no passwordless. After logging in, I need to set a variable and perform an `if`- `then`- `else`. 
After the work is complete, it should create a file on the local machine, not on the remote one. The (local) file will contain the hostname(s) of the machines where certain process wasn't running.

The general idea is:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    sshpass -p ******** ssh "mydomain1\admin1"@$line bash -s << EOF
    pwd=*********
    var=$"(ps -ef | grep http | grep -v grep | wc -l)"
    if (( var > 0 ))
    then
        echo  "$pwd" | sudo -S ps -ef | grep patrol | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
        echo  "$pwd" | sudo -S rm -rf /data/abc /etc/efg 
        #need to create the log on local machine, not on remote machine
        hostname >> /find.txt
    else
        #need to create the log on local machine, not on the remote machine
        hostname >> /agentnotthere.txt
    fi
EOF
#servers.txt contains server names
done < servers.txt
```

Obviously lines 5-16 of the above form a here document
containing commands to run on the remote host. 
In that here document,
I have commands `hostname >> /find.txt` and `hostname >> /agentnotthere.txt`. 
As stated in my introductory paragraph, and again in comments in the code,
I want the (remote) hostname to be written to a local file,
not a file on the remote machine. 
Obviously, a `command >> filename` command
on the remote machine will write to a file ***on the remote machine***.

How can I get my script,
which uses `ssh` to run a few commands on remote machine(s),
to write output to a local file
based on the results of test(s) performed on the remote machine?

Comment: Ok. What's not working?

Comment: Sudo su and creating the file on local machine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to do what you wanted, meaning writing to separate files on your local host from a script that's executing on a remote machine.

You can easily pipe the output of the script to one local file, though:

```
ssh host << EOF > output_file              
some commands
to be executed
EOF
```

With that, you can restructure the script so that it executes `ssh` multiple times (this will increase the `ssh` overhead, but you can mitigate most of it by using `ControlPersist` in the `ssh` config file).

So instead you'll end up with something like this (pseudo-bash):

```
echo "get the output of var script" | ssh host > var_value
if var read from the file is more than zero; then
  echo "the thing you want" | ssh host >> /find.txt
else
  echo "the other thing you want" | ssh host >> /agentnotthere.txt
fi
```

This should suit your use case just fine :)

My two cents about the script itself:

- Ansible or one of the other configuration management tools is probably better suited to this task instead of writing bash scripts
- Using SSH passwords instead of key auth is bad from a security standpoint. But I've been in situations where it's impossible to implement that either because of company policy/old embedded stuff that doesn't support it/etc.
- Instead of using the old `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep something` boilerplate, you can use `pgrep` and `pkill`. They are in standard `coreutils`, so unless you use really antique systems they should be available on them

Comment: Can we pass password also? I am looking for the solution to automate. Don't want to give password each time. There has to be a way to automate in the shell script or we can try "expect" to pass password and all.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see an issue with that. I used `ssh user@host` instead of `sshpass -p pass ssh user@host` in my examples because it's shorter ;)

Comment: one more thing I have to use </dev/null end of ssh line otherwise loop is ending when it disconnects from ssh :(